# Conditional where variable array is not empty, but has NULL values

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, null, conditional-statements

I have the following problem in my php function:

$items is an array.  It is never empty, But sometimes it has only has NULL values which returns an array value of [0]. How do I convert the conditional to say:  If $items is not empty and if the $items array does not return a value of [0], then do this. . . ?

Thanks.

```
        $items = Items_Model_Item::findBy(array('where' => new JO_Db_Expr('item.id IN (SELECT id FROM dbtable WHERE challengeId LIKE ' . Helper_Db::quote($challengeIDPLUS['code']) . ')')));

        if (!empty($items))  {
            foo

        } else {
            bar
        }
```

Comment: please tag the question with the  framework used

Comment: "is never empty, but it sometimes only has NULL values" --- I've read it 3 times and still cannot get how something is never but sometimes.

Comment: `!empty($items) && $expr !== null`

Comment: sorry for confusing language, zerkms.  New to the coding thing and discussing it. Just changed the language to try to make it clearer.